# Harmfull suggested edit got approved

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just re-edited an approved suggested edit, which made my answer wrong.
Is there a better way to undo these things?

https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/338370

Comment: You need to discuss this on Meta Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: No better way, and you can post a comment reply to the editor, telling him why his edit was wrong.

Comment: You can click the "rollback" link in [the revision history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/544108/revisions) to revert to the prior revision.